# Creating an image file throws "permission denied" exception

Tags: android

I'm trying to take a picture and save it somewhere. I'm using this code to create a `tempfile` for the `image`.

```
long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String imageFileName = "NAME_" + timeStamp;
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
        File image = null;
        try {
           
            image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return image;
```

but I get `java.io.IOException: Permission denied` even though i have the permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

What's causing this?

Comment: Have you asked the user for permission at runtime? Because writing in manifest is not enough. See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting if you have done this then please post that code here.

Comment: Also add this to your Manifest.xml 
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Comment: A lot depends on the Android version of the used device/emulator.